# Serialize form to string and deserealize it later to complex view model

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm implementing the "Save Draft" functionality on my dynamically generated page and trying to make it as generic as possible. All my controllers and pages should support it and that's why I thought about creating a `SaveDraft()` POST action in my base controller which will receive a serialized form as a string which can be directly saved into the database and deserialized to a view model later in the specific get action using specific view model

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveDraft(string jsonData, long id)
```

My first idea was to create the generic base controller and pass the view model type to it but the problem is that some controllers have multiple differently named POST actions and using different view model types, **I cant change it now**.

Some view models are complex and looking like

```
public class CollateralsDataModel
{
    //...
    public List<Applicant> Applicants { get; set; }
}

public class Applicant
{
    public long ApplicantId { get; set; }
    public IList<RealEstateSecurityCollateralsDTO> RealEstateSecurityCollaterals { get; set; }
    public IList<AdditionalCollateralDTO> AdditionalCollaterals { get; set; }
}

public class RealEstateSecurityCollateralsDTO
{
    [Required]
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(CollateralsData), Name = nameof(CollateralsData.RealEstateSecurityType))]
    public int? RealEstateSecurityTypeId { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

The input names on the form are looking like

```
"Applicants[0].MortgageApplicantId": "11595",
"Applicants[0].RealEstateSecurityCollaterals[0].Id": "17",
"Applicants[1].MortgageApplicantId": "11596",
"Applicants[1].RealEstateSecurityCollaterals.Index": "0",
"Applicants[1].AdditionalCollaterals[0].Id": "138",
"Applicants[1].AdditionalCollaterals[0].AdditionalCollateralTypeId": "4",
```

**My question is - how can I serialize them to the string so I can deserialize it later?**

I tried using different combinations of

```
$('.draft-data-form').serializeArray() 
$('.draft-data-form').serialize()
JSON.stringify($('.draft-data-form').serializeArray());
```

but in my Action I get the flat JSON structure and I can't deserialize it

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CollateralsDataModel>(jsonData);
```

*Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type '...CollateralsDataModel' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.*

I've also tried to deserialize it as a list but then I get the List of 115 entries

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CollateralsDataModel>>(jsonData);
```

**So my question is - how can I serialize them to the string so I can deserialize it later?**

Comment: "but then I get the List of 115 entries" - well, is that correct? if not: can you filter it first?

Comment: Important note: anything that goes to the client and back **must be considered harmful and contaminated**. You cannot trust **anything** that you accept from the client to be unchanged; be **very** careful that you don't let people use their browser tools to review other people's mortgages simply by changing the value in a hidden form input. That's a good way to get huge legal costs.

Comment: @MarcGravell "but then I get the List of 115 entries" - well, is that correct? if not: can you filter it first?"
No as I get 115 instances of my view model with some data filled instead of one

Comment: @MarcGravell I am aware of this but don't really see how it can be a  problem in my case as I'm just saving the incomplete data as serialized string to show it later. Anyway, it's a back office application, only the employee will use it.

Comment: it is a good job that back-office employees are always 100% trustworthy and would *never* abuse a weakness in a system or process, then :)

Comment: @MarcGravell hehe let's be more specific then, please tell me if I miss something ;)
The mean employee could manipulate the id of the mortgage application and if I don't do any checks before writing the data in the database, then the draft is saved for a different mortgage application AND then this other mortgage application is shown, then the wrong draft data is loaded onto the view. So the employee can view the draft data from another incomplete mortgage application which he can view anyway without manipulation... :)

Comment: it was partly in jest, but in many scenarios it isn't the case that all employees have read and/or write access to all data, and it has been known for people to abuse systems to read - or make alterations to - data they shouldn't have had that access to; bonus points if you can convince the audit records to blame "Sean from accounting" rather than the perpetrator

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to serialize/deserialize a List. Only a single instance of the model.

I would guess that the error is in instantiating the list within the model. I know that the DataContractSerializer has an issue where if the List is not instantiated to an empty list when the model is constructed then the deserialization is unable to add to it.

Not sure if this is the same problem you are facing but could be worth a try.

eg. use:

```
public List<Applicant> Applicants { get; set; } = new List<Applicant>();
```

Comment: I think my problem is rather that I'm trying to create the complex, nested object containg lists using the flat JSON object :/

Comment: Because you serialized it as an array. Use .serialize() instead.

Comment: I wrote in the question that I've tried it as well.

Comment: With the change I suggested?

Comment: I tried to instantiate it, but this makes no sense as serialize() creates a plain GET parameter string so it can't be serialized either